# jQuery search through table rows, hidden and visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a table where i display message history. By default the table displays only the last message between two people. But all of the messages are in the `HTML` code, just that they are set with `display:none;`

Im trying to make the search go through both visible and hidden tr rows.

What i currently have:

HTML:

```
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="tDefault mytasks" id="history">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Finish design</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong class="grey">0%</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Aquincum HTML code</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong class="green">89%</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="display:none;">
                        <td>Aquincum cpp code</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong class="green">99%</strong></td>
                    </tr>                            

                    <tr>
                        <td>Fix buggy css styles</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong class="red">16%</strong></td>
                    </tr>

            </table>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    $("#history tr").each(function (index) {
        if (!index) return;
        $(this).find("td").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
            var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
            $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
            return not_found;
        });
    });
});
```

I have two problems:

1. For some reason the first `tr` is always visible even through it does not match the search. Try to search for `buggy css`. You'll see that the first `tr` is still there.
2. When i search for something, and then clear the search field. The second `tr` which is by default set to `display:none;` is visible. It has to somehow go back to a `display:none` state

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2T5yJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first row index is zero. So its not reaching

```
        $(this).find("td").each(function () {
```

Remove

```
 if (!index) return;
```

And search filter would work correct

Update you can check if `value=""` and write logic to get back display of rows to original

Please check updated fiddle

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2T5yJ/5/)

Comment: Searches all `tr`s but wont re-hide the `Aquincum cpp code`