# Javascript search table rows but ignore search on the hidden collapsible accordion rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I have a table, there is a toggle feature that uses accordion collapse rows. I have a search function in javascript, but when you search text and that text is not in the hidden rows the toggle doesn't work. It won't display the hidden rows unless there is the search text. Please help!

i need it to do this but with javascript not ajax... http://www.cscc.edu/_resources/app-data/datatables/examples/api/row_details.html

My table has two hidden tables, each with a header, within it...
i can id the tr's of the collapsible rows.

So for each row in the table, there are two tables that expand when user select toggler. Two headers will display even if no rows.

Below is javscript for the search functionality that i need to have not search on the collapsible tables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $(".search").keyup(function () {
                  var searchTerm = $(".search").val();
                  var listItem = $('.results tbody').children('tr');
                  var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

                  $.extend($.expr[':'], {
                      'containsi': function (elem, i, match, array) {
                          return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
                      }
                  });

                  $(".results tbody tr").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function (e) {
                      $(this).attr('visible', 'false');
                  });

                  $(".results tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function (e) {
                      $(this).attr('visible', 'true');
                  });

                  var jobCount = $('.results tbody tr[visible="true"]').length;
                  $('.counter').text(jobCount + ' item');

                  if (jobCount == '0') { $('.no-result').show(); }
                  else { $('.no-result').hide(); }


              });
          });
</script>
```

html...

```
<div class="form-group pull-right">
    <input type="text" class="search form-control" placeholder="What you looking for?" id="search">
</div>
<span class="counter pull-right"></span>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered results" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Obj ID</th>
            <th>Obj</th>
            <th>Init ID</th>
            <th>Init</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="warning no-result">
            <td colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> No result</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo_1" class="accordion-toggle">
                <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></td>
                <td scope="row">1</td>
                <td>Obj 1</td>
                <td scope="row">1</td>
                <td>Task 1</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo_1">
                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr style="background-color: darkgrey" id="header_1">
                                                <th>Update ID</th>
                                                <th>Stop Light</th>
                                                <th>Status</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                                <tr style="background-color: lightgrey" id="update_1">
                                                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                                                    <td>Notes for Update 1</td>
                                                    <td>Other Notes for Update 1</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
                                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr style="background-color: darkgrey" id="header_2" >
                                                                <th>Target Quarter</th>
                                                                <th>Added By</th>
                                                                <th>Added On</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                                <tr style="background-color: lightgrey" id="target_1">
                                                                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                                                                    <td>User 1</td>
                                                                    <td>1/1/2017</td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Show relevant html as per [mcve]. Also...don't extend `$.expr` inside the event handler. It only needs to be done once per page load

Comment: You want to search only into the expanded tables? It's not clear from your description...

Comment: I would like to search only on what is not expanded... so the most parent table should only be included in the search function

Comment: just added the table html so you can see what im working with

Comment: Only add raw html. Your server code is useless in the browser where the javascript runs

Comment: ok, that should do it...hopefully

Comment: anything with a background color of grey light or dark is the "history" or detail rows....so the toggle will expand those table rows. But when you search the page , if the text is not within those history rows then you can't expand them

Comment: This is what i need it to do http://www.cscc.edu/_resources/app-data/datatables/examples/api/row_details.html    but with javascript i don't have ajax

Comment: this is the closest i can find https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cg978hgj/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655673/jquery-search-through-table-rows-hidden-and-visible?rq=1   also similar